# How to store value as a boolean in a select?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to store the value from a select as a boolean and not a string in my Next.js project. Right now the behavior of the select component below is saving it as a string.

```js
export default function Status({ register }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="Status" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-white">
        Status
      </label>
      <select
        id="Status"
        name="Status"
        {...register("isActive", {})}
      >
        <option value={true}>Active</option>
        <option value={false}>Inactive</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I store the value as a boolean instead of a string?

Comment: did you try wrapping the values in `Boolean`...for example: `Boolean(true)`

Comment: I just tried `value={Boolean(true)}` and that did not work. Hm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a workaround to force it to convert to a Boolean, something like this:

```
      <select
        {...register("isActive", {
          setValueAs: (v) => Boolean(v)
        })}
      >
        <option value={true}>Active</option> //Boolean("any string") gives true
        <option value={""}>Inactive</option> //Boolean("") gives false
      </select>
```

`setValueAs` returns the input value by running it through a function, and since the input produce string at submitting, the only way to force it to make it `Boolean` is by passing an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I can't comment, big brain stackoverflow, ok however.

Erm, since you're storing as a string, I recommend attaching the value to a string, then have a useEffect run with the state as a dependency setting your own personal state that is a boolean. For example

```
useEffect(() => {setMyState(value === "isActive" ? true : false)}, [value])
```

I'm having a bit too big of a brain fart, ima just imitate it.

```
const Component = () => {
  // your component, let's say you have these two states
  const [linkedState, setLinkedState] = useState("")
  const [booleanState, setBooleanState] = useState("")
  // this state is linked to the string value, you then make a 
  useEffect with the state as dependency
  useEffect(() => {
    // this happens when linkedState changes
    setBooleanState(linkedState === "isActive" ? true : false)
    // if linkedState equals isActive it sets your boolean to true, else it goes false
   }, [linkedState])
}
```

Comment: That sounds promising. What would the full code look like if you add your part to mine?

Comment: I like it. I'll test it out later. :)